# shinobi grid ios : change background color of a complete line

Tags: ios, shinobi

I'm using shinobi grids on iOS to display some datas.
I'd like to change the background color of a complete line, when I select a cell in a row.

Does someone has a sample code to achieve this ?
thx

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, quite simple :

[myGrid setSelectionMode:SGridSelectionModeRowSingle];